# Metal drawable musings... ugh

Tags: core-animation, metal, metalkit

I have two issues in my Metal App.

- My call to `currentPassDescriptor` is stalling.  I have too many drawables, apparently.
- I'm wholly confused on how to **most** performantly configure the multiple `MTKViews` I am using.

---

Issue (1)

I have a problem with `currentPassDescriptor` in my app.  It is occasionally blocking (for 1.00s) which, according to the docs, is because there is no `currentDrawable` available.

Background: I have 4 HD 1920x1080 videos playing concurrently, tiled out onto a 3840x2160 second external display as a debugging configuration.  The pixel buffers of these `AVPlayer` instances are captured by 4 independent `CVDIsplayLink` callbacks and, from within the callback, there is the draw call to its assigned `MTKView`.  A total of 4 `MTKViews` are subviews tiled on a single `NSWindow`, and are configured for manual drawing.

I'm using `CVDisplayLink` callbacks manually.  If I don't, then I get stutter when mousing up on the app’s menus, for example.

Within each draw call, I do a bit of kernel shader work then attempt to obtain the `currentPassDescriptor`.  If successful, I do one pass of a fragment/vertex shader and then present the drawable.  My code flow follows Apple’s sample code as well as published examples.

According to the Metal System Trace, most of draw calls take under 5ms.  The GPU is about 20-25% utilized and there’s about 25% of the GPU memory free.  I can also cause the main thread to `usleep()` for 1 second without any hiccups.

Without any user interaction, there’s about a 5% chance of the videos stalling out in the first minute.  If there’s some UI work going then I see that as `windowServer` work in Instruments.  I also note that `AVFoundation` seems to cache about 15 frames of video onto the GPU for each `AVPlayer`.

If the cadence of the draw calls is upset, there's about a 10% chance that things stall completely or some of the videos -- some will completely stall, some will stall with 1hz updates, some won't stall at all.  There's also less chance of stalling when running Metal System Trace.  The movies that have stalled seem to have done so on obtaining a `currentPassDescriptor`.

This is really a poor design to have this `currentPassDescriptor` block for ≈1s during a render loop.  So much so that I’m thinking of eschewing the `MTKView` all together and just drawing to a `CAMetalLayer` myself. But the docs on `CAMetalLayer` seem to indicate the same blocking behaviour will occur.

I also grab these 4 pixel buffers on the fly and render sub-size regions-of-interest to 4 smaller `MTKViews` on the main monitor; but the stutters still occur if this code is removed.

**Is the drawable buffer limit per `MTKView` or per the backing `CALayer`?**  The docs for `maximumDrawableCount` on `CAMetalLayer` say the number needs to be 2 or 3.  This question ties into the configuration of the views.

---

Issue (2)

My current setup is a 3840x2160 `NSWindow` with a single content view.  This subclass of `NSView` does some hiding/revealing of the mouse cursor by introducing an `NSTrackingRectTag`.  The `MTKViews` are tiled subviews on this content view.

**Is this the best configuration?**  Namely, one `NSWindow` with tiled `MTKViews`… or should I do one `MTKView` per window?

I'm also not sure how to best configure these windows/layers — ie. by setting (or clearing) `wantsLayer`, `wantsUpdateLayer`, and/or `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer`.  I'm currently just setting `wantsLayer` to YES on the single content view.  **Any hints on this would be great.**

**Does adjusting these properties collapse all the available drawables to the backing layer only; are there still 2 or 3 per `MTKView`?**

---

NB: I've attached a sample run of my Metal app.  The longest 'work' on the top graph is just under 5ms.  The clumps of green/blue are rendering on the 4 MTKViews.  The 'work' alternates a bit because one of the videos is a 60fps source; the others are all 30fps.

[image]

Comment: So, in terms of overall performance, would it be possible for you to use a single large MTKView and render the 4 CVPixelBuffers into the one single view? I honestly don't know if that would improve your situation, but it seems like it would reduce the number of different drawables being allocated at the same time on each frame render.

Comment: I went with one MTKView per NSWindow and (eventually) one NSWindow per monitor; by going with one MTKView per window (not four), I was able to rectify the issue. Good suggestion, though!